# Stripping lxml root tags in python

Tags: python, lxml

Given the example countries.xml file, I am looking to copy each country to a new output.xml file, as subelements of a new root. The problem is when I append each country, I am getting duplicate subelement tags in the output file.

Reference xml:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I am looking to append the countries from one file to another, and remove the extra subelement tags  if possible. The etree.strip_tags function will not work due to "country" being a root element.

Example python script:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(r'countries.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

new_root = etree.Element('NewData')

for country in root.iter('country'):
    new_country = etree.SubElement(new_root,'country')
    new_country.append(country)

with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(new_root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Current output with duplicate "country" tags:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<NewData>
  <country><country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    </country>
  <country><country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    </country>
  <country><country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</country>
</NewData>
```

Expected output (which is basically original XML with updated root name currently):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewData>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</NewData>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the `for` loop. What are the elements that you want to add to the `new_root`? (Hint: maybe you already have them?) When you do `new_country = etree.SubElement(new_root,'country')`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? (Did you try to read the documentation for `etree.SubElement`, in order to understand this clearly?) When you do `new_country.append(country)`, what do you expect this to mean, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want

```
tree = etree.parse(r'countries.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

new_root = etree.Element('NewData')

for country in root.iter('country'):
    new_root.append(country)
```

Of course transforming/manipulating XML is perhaps better done with XSLT where you have with Python now the option to use XSLT 1.0 with lxml or XSLT 3.0 with saxonche.

Comment: I believe this works. I just needed to add an additional new line character as the new_root.text `new_root.text = '\n'` to get the formatting correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the input and output only differ by the name of the root, why not change that?

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(r"countries.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag = "NewData"
with open("output.xml", "wb") as stream:
    stream.write(
        etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
    )
```

Comment: I was using this a simple example to see if it was feasible to copy the subelements from one file to another and remove the tags. Ultimately it will be used to build new XML documents that are composites of other documents without having to iterate through each subelement to rewrite.